# C# ASP.NET MVC5 + Worker Role (no Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, backgroundworker, worker

I have been looking for a starting point to this problem for a while now, and I have exhausted my search efforts.

I (think I) want to include a worker role in my new MVC5 project.  This will be hosted on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8 inside my corporations intranet (meaning I can not use Azure web services).  The purpose of this additional piece of software would be to parse XML files supplied by the user, which would then create objects saving data to the back-end database (in the worker role), later being retrieved by the controllers and displayed in the views.

I am not foreign to the concept of a worker role, I have written a web crawler although this was a long time ago and was not with an MVC5 web role as an additional component.  So I understand that a worker-role consists of while(true) and a waiting component. So I guess my questions to the community here are two-fold:

1. Am I correct in the solution I have hypothesized?  Is a worker role ran locally in the same instance of IIS how I want to handle large text processing for my MVC5 application?  If not, what are my other options?
2. Do you have a link, a guide, an example, anything to get me started on how to link the two of these up? I know they need to communicate through a queue, but I do not have the faintest Idea where to create the worker role, in the same solution? next to the solution of my MVC5 project? etc.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: No. In Azure Cloud Service terms a role is hosted on a machine/multiple machines. 2 roles will not co-exist on the same machine. Your web role and worker roles will deploy to separate machines.

Comment: I am not using Azure Cloud Services as this is an enterprise application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to accomplish your goal you need to write the worker role as a traditional c# console app. You can't run a worker role or console app in your MVC project. They can run locally in the same machine (locally or in an VM) but they aren't hosted by the same process. Instead you will run two projects separately and use some communication mechanism like a queue service, database table, bus service. Tip: On azure, web roles and worker roles are in fact a VMs running a host process, on worker role this process is called WaWorkerHost, on web role is called WaIISHost. [More info here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/05/windows-azure-role-architecture.aspx)

1) In your MVC project you received the user input and save it for processing later. After that you send a message to the to queue or bus (if you are using a sql table, you put a new register on that table).

2) In your worker project. You have an endless loop waiting for a new message in the queue or bus (or new records in a sql table). When a new message arrived with the info about the user input, then you do the work, after that you sleep X milliseconds. Wake up and try to read another message.

I applied this approach successful using Microsoft Azure Webjobs (Workers) + Azure queues (Communication channel) + Azure Websites (MVC project).

[DotNetMQ a simple and open source queue library for interprocess communication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193611/DotNetMQ-A-Complete-Message-Queue-System-for-NET)

[Azure Queues. A cloud-based queue system](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/)

[Web Role + Worker Role communication using Azure service bus](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-multi-tier-app-using-service-bus-queues/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this out, I don't know why we are getting down-voted to oblivion. =/ Is Azure Microsoft's cloud hosting program?? This application is for my corporation (within a data farm), so I will be unable to call out and use Azure web roles.

Comment: Yeah, Azure is the Cloud of Microsoft. You don't  need azure. You can accomplish the same goal without it. You only need an queue library for communication. Try RabbitMQ or DotNetMQ

Comment: Thank you Kellerman, at this point I will give you the answer and give DotNetMQ a try.  Do I start by just creating a Console Application in the same solution as my MVC program?

Comment: Exactly. Install DotNetMQ in both projects and try to communicate them. After that the rest of work is more easy.